# 4 posts in one page?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Have page that it displays 4 posts from several selected categories ('cat' => '3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11'). Layout is like this:
layout:
[image: layout]

I can use

```
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'cat' => '3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
     );
            $arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :
    $arr_posts->the_post();
```

but it has to fit into the layout.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would use CSS Grid to achieve that layout.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.post-container {
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.post-container:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.post-container:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.post-container:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

.post-container:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- loop posts in here -->
  
  <div class="post-container">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <!-- category goes here -->
      </div>      
  </div>
  
  <div class="post-container">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <!-- category goes here -->
      </div>      
  </div>
  
  <div class="post-container">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <!-- category goes here -->
      </div>      
  </div>
  
  <div class="post-container">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <!-- category goes here -->
      </div>      
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```